# Venn diagram of all possibles combinations of 5 number

Tags: permutation

I’m trying to take 5 random integers between 1 and 100, obtain with them all the possibles operations using only each number one time for every operation.

```
a=RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 3]

m1 = a[[1]]*a[[2 ;; -1]]
m2 = a[[2]]*a[[3 ;; -1]]]
a1 = a[[1]] + a[[2 ;; -1]]
a2 = a[[2]] + a[[3 ;; -1]]]
ma1 = a[[1]]*a[[2]] + a[[3]]
ma2 = a[[1]] + a[[2]]*a[[3]]
ma3 = a[[2]] + a[[3]]*a[[1]]
```

...

> I want to do that but for n numbers, it is possible?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish? Maybe my grasp on venn diagrams is incomplete but I don't see what single integers have to do with operations on sets?

Comment: The venn diagram is not important, i’m trying to see all the different ways you can reach to a number. If i take a group of every operation and intersect if they reach the same number if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not certain that I fully understand your question but if you want to get all combinations of `Plus` and `Times` between a list of variables here is one method.

**Step 1.** Create a list of the variables

In this example five variables will be used but it can be extended to any number.

```
list = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}
(* {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5} *)

len = Length@list
(* 5 *)
```

**Step 2.** Create a list of all possible operator combinations

```
ptList = Tuples[{Plus, Times}, len - 1]
(* {{Plus, Plus, Plus, Plus}, {Plus, Plus, Plus, Times}, {Plus, 
  Plus, Times, Plus}, {Plus, Plus, Times, Times}, {Plus, Times, Plus, 
  Plus}, {Plus, Times, Plus, Times}, {Plus, Times, Times, 
  Plus}, {Plus, Times, Times, Times}, {Times, Plus, Plus, 
  Plus}, {Times, Plus, Plus, Times}, {Times, Plus, Times, 
  Plus}, {Times, Plus, Times, Times}, {Times, Times, Plus, 
  Plus}, {Times, Times, Plus, Times}, {Times, Times, Times, 
  Plus}, {Times, Times, Times, Times}} *)
```

**Step 3.** Use `Map`, `Function` and `Fold` to generate the numbers

Below the use of `Fold` is the main worker.

As an example, here is `Fold` applied to the sixth element of `ptList`.

```
Transpose[{ptList[[6]], Rest[list]}]
(* {{Plus, a2}, {Times, a3}, {Plus, a4}, {Times, a5}} *)

Fold[#2[[1]][#1, #2[[2]]] &, list[[1]], 
 Transpose[{ptList[[6]], Rest[list]}]]
(* ((a1 + a2) a3 + a4) a5 *)
```

Use `Map` to apply this to each sublist of ptList.

```
Map[
 Function[operations,
  With[
   {
    operatorParameterList = Transpose[{operations, Rest[list]}]
    },
   Fold[#2[[1]][#1, #2[[2]]] &, list[[1]], operatorParameterList]
   ]
  ],
 ptList
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Perfect, I really thought that been Mathematica, an obscure way of doing that much easer would exist. But that will work just fine.